# from PyQt5.QWebEngineWidgets import * Does not work

Tags: python3, pyqt5

I tried Installing and uninstalling PyQtWebEngine with pip3 install PyQtWebEngine (Did not work) What am i doing wrong
code

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *
import os
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


        self.browser = QWebEngineView()

        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://google.com"))

        self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.update_urlbar)

        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.update_title)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        self.status = QStatusBar()

        self.setStatusBar(self.status)

        navtb = QToolBar("Navigation")

        self.addToolBar(navtb)

        back_btn = QAction("Back", self)

        back_btn.setStatusTip("Back to previous page")

        back_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.back)

        navtb.addAction(back_btn)

        next_btn = QAction("Forward", self)
        next_btn.setStatusTip("Forward to next page")

        next_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward)
        navtb.addAction(next_btn)

        reload_btn = QAction("Reload", self)
        reload_btn.setStatusTip("Reload page")

        reload_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload)
        navtb.addAction(reload_btn)

        home_btn = QAction("Home", self)
        home_btn.setStatusTip("Go home")
        home_btn.triggered.connect(self.navigate_home)
        navtb.addAction(home_btn)

        navtb.addSeparator()

        self.urlbar = QLineEdit()

        self.urlbar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)

        navtb.addWidget(self.urlbar)

        stop_btn = QAction("Stop", self)
        stop_btn.setStatusTip("Stop loading current page")


        stop_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.stop)
        navtb.addAction(stop_btn)

        self.show()


    def update_title(self):
        title = self.browser.page().title()
        self.setWindowTitle("% s - Not virus" % title)


    def navigate_home(self):

        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))

    def navigate_to_url(self):


        q = QUrl(self.urlbar.text())


        if q.scheme() == "":

            q.setScheme("http")


        self.browser.setUrl(q)



    def update_urlbar(self, q):

        # setting text to the url bar
        self.urlbar.setText(q.toString())

        # setting cursor position of the url bar
        self.urlbar.setCursorPosition(1)



app = QApplication(sys.argv)


app.setApplicationName("Not virus")

window = MainWindow()

# loop
app.exec_()
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using, yes it does matter.

Comment: You are missing a t: QWebEngineWidgets s/b QtWebEngineWidgets

Answer (score 0):

what makes you decide to install the module directly through pip instead of the `python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine` package as available via `apt`?

As [David](https://askubuntu.com/users/1134215/david) mentioned, the latest Python library version may not compatible with older versions of the Qt5 library, and yes, Ubuntu (mostly) ships older versions, and even older ones depending on the current Ubuntu version you're running.

At least installing the library though `apt` still guarantees that you're using the right PyQt5 and Qt5 versions available on your Ubuntu version.